# SQL where clause not getting filtered

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query, but it is not giving any regard to the  in the `p.created_by =@searchBy` where clause, how to correct it so that the results would be filtered according @searchBy too.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Rptcashcollectionouter] @branchId INT, 
                                          @searchBy INT, 
                                          @strDate  DATETIME=NULL, 
                                          @endDate  DATETIME=NULL 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT DISTINCT p.created_on AS paid_date 
      FROM   reading re 
             JOIN billing_gen bg ON re.id = bg.reading_id 
             JOIN customer_registration cr ON bg.account_number = cr.account_number 
             JOIN payment p ON bg.bill_number = p.bill_number 
             JOIN customer_category cc ON cr.customer_category_id = cc.id 
      WHERE  p.created_by = @searchBy 
             AND ( ( @strDate IS NULL ) 
                    OR Cast(Floor(Cast(p.created_on AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) >= 
                       Cast(Floor(Cast(@strDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) ) 
             AND ( ( @endDate IS NULL ) 
                    OR Cast(Floor(Cast(p.created_on AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) <= 
                       Cast(Floor(Cast(@endDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) ) 
             AND cr.branch_id = @branchId 
      ORDER  BY p.created_on ASC; 
  END;
```

Comment: Sample data and expected result would certainly help

Answer (score 0):

Check the value inside your procedure as below.

```
SELECT @branchId, @searchBy, @strDate,@endDate
```

And, then try to run the SQL manually with the same value. Also, make sure you have data in your table for your criteria.

Also, what exactly you are trying here ?

```
Cast(Floor(Cast(p.created_on AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. While executing procedure, make sure you are passing properly value.
2. Print out all values that are coming (Just for testing).
3. @searchBy INT is of integer type. But i think "p.created_by =@searchBy" is a type of datetime or date , so it may also conflicts here, or display wrong result. In below line. p.created_by is treating as a datetime or date and @searchby in integer.

   WHERE  p.created_by = @searchBy

Comment: no it is an int holding the id of staff who created the payment

Comment: If p.created_by is an int (that is holding the id of  staff), then what you doing here.." Cast(Floor(Cast(p.created_on AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)". Explain it or send some sample data so that i can execute and check it.

Comment: p.created_on is the date p.created_by is the user id

Comment: Ok Hamza, Now just need to check manually first whether data is available in table (according to this condition) or not. Except data, everything is looking correct to me.

Comment: But there is nothing wrong with the data, just found out that it is working exactly as I want when I remove select distinct from the query.